# Unable to use "help" in a question title

Tags: support

I tried to create a question with "help" in the title, and got an error message. Switching to "assist" worked fine. Is this a bug?

Comment: Not a bug, it's a blacklist. Things like "help" (and, incidentally, "problem"), are usually an indicator of a terrible question title.

Answer (score 11):

["I am captive please help"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8977817/i-am-captive-pleasehelp) is not a good question title.

A question title should summarize your problem. Most titles with the words "problem" or "help" in it don't do that; this is why Stack Overflow automatically blocks them, in a (sometimes futile) attempt to make the asker think about how to improve it.

Solution: find a better question title. In your case for example, "Visual Studio remains on top after compiling C# assembly" could be one.

Comment: i am not understand.. is document available for review for Ask Question Guidlines ?

Comment: @Prashant there is the help section: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask  essentially, the question title should give the reader a rough idea what the question is about. You have to admit "I am captive please help" doesn't do that. It doesn't tell the reader anything about Visual Studio and the window staying on top.

Comment: It's not a good question title, it's an *awesome* question title. Just not very descriptive is all.

Comment: @lunboks yeah. It's a fine title; it just doesn't work on SO

Comment: i am sorry.. i was of thinking title is fun.. i did not mean for offence

Comment: @Prashant Don't worry - your title is not offensive to anyone, it's just not *useful*, it doesn't help understand the question. Stack Overflow has 4000 new question a day, so people need a quick overview of what to expect before clicking a link.