# "Help" slipped through in a question title although it should be blocked

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, title, blocklist

As we all know the word "help" [is blacklisted from questions title](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/120065/unable-to-use-help-in-a-question-title).

However today I encountered [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12881321/replacing-n-with-0a) on Stack Overflow and when submitting my edit (not related to the title) was amazed to see it blocked. Putting my amazement aside I removed it manually from the title and the edit went through.

Here is the original revision: https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/12881321/1

Is there something we don't know about the title blacklisted words?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A while ago we [changed the `help` filter](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/109011/too-many-restrictions-in-titles/109040#109040) to allow help in a handful of cases.

The price for fewer false positives in more false negatives, so this question slipped through,

Comment: Thanks, I missed that one.